# Debugging Test functions in Golang

Tags: go, ubuntu, debugging, visual-studio-code

i am new in go and want to debug some test functions.

Ubuntu:
21.10
Go:
1.18.3 linux/amd64
VsCode:
1.69.0
Go Plugin:
0.34.1
Delve Debugger:
1.9.0

Tools environment: GOPATH=/home/fred/go
Installing 7 tools at /home/fred/go/bin in module mode.
gotests
gomodifytags
impl
goplay
dlv
staticcheck
gopls

All tools successfully installed. You are ready to Go. :)

I would like to debug test functions.

- I have installed go with the following instruction: https://go.dev/doc/install.
- I have installed the golang plugin for vscode.
- then via ctrl+shift+p Go:updates/tools installed the tools.
  I tried the same thing on a WIndows PC. There everything works fine. above the test functions there are two buttons displayed "test run" and "test debug". These work! [buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lShOK.png)
  -> Now to my problem. These buttons are not displayed in vscode on Ubuntu. And if I use the plugin function "Go: Debug test at curor" it always shows me "no function at cursor".
  Does anyone know why the buttons are not displayed?
  How can I still debug the test function without these buttons?
  I have googled but I can't get it to work.

Comment: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/1924 have a look at this. Might be related.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.